# Why can't I use categories: Map<String, Boolean> when I do a deep copy with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following Code A is from the project https://github.com/enpassio/Databinding

I can't understand why the author need use `newCategories.putAll(categories)` for deep copy.

I think that Code B can do the same thing, right?

**Code A**

```
data class ToyEntry(
    var toyName: String,
    var categories: Map<String, Boolean>,
    var gender: Gender = Gender.UNISEX,
    var procurementType: ProcurementType? = null,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val toyId: Int = 0
): Parcelable{

    /*This function is needed for a healthy comparison of two items,
    particularly for detecting changes in the contents of the map.
    Native copy method of the data class assign a map with same reference
    to the copied item, so equals() method cannot detect changes in the content.*/
    fun copy() : ToyEntry{
        val newCategories = mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>()
        newCategories.putAll(categories)
        return ToyEntry(toyName, newCategories, gender, procurementType, toyId)
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
data class ToyEntry(
    var toyName: String,
    var categories: Map<String, Boolean>,
    var gender: Gender = Gender.UNISEX,
    var procurementType: ProcurementType? = null,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val toyId: Int = 0
): Parcelable{

    /*This function is needed for a healthy comparison of two items,
    particularly for detecting changes in the contents of the map.
    Native copy method of the data class assign a map with same reference
    to the copied item, so equals() method cannot detect changes in the content.*/
    fun copy() : ToyEntry{       
        return ToyEntry(toyName, categories, gender, procurementType, toyId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your B sample, you're passing the same reference to the map through your copied object, so any logic mutating `categories` would affect both instances.

Btw, a data class already implements a `copy()` method, it seems the original author of "Code A" wanted to change the implementation to return a new instance of Map for `categories`.

Consider this code:

```
val categoriesOne = mutableMapOf("A" to false)
val entry = ToyEntry(
    toyName = "Foo",
    categories = categoriesOne
)
val entryCopy = entry.copy()

println(entry == entryCopy) // true
categoriesOne.put("B", true)
println(entry == entryCopy) // what does this print?
```

"Code A" would print `false` and "Code B" would print `true` because your `copy` implementation is re-using the same map.